# Change Freeform redirect URL according to checkbox field

Tags: craft3, redirect, plugin-freeform

Is it at all possible to set a different Redirect URL on a FreeForm form if a checkbox is checked? To summarise, I have a FreeForm form which contains a checkbox. I would like the submission redirect URL to differ depending on whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Can anyone shed any light on this and offer some advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable. If you have a field in your formatting template with the name `formReturnUrl`, when checked, it would override the Freeform return URL. You'd likely need to manually hardcode this into your form template code though:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="formReturnUrl" value="{{ siteUrl }}freeform-demo/bootstrap/my-url" />
```